# Getting wrong results when exponentiating large integers

Tags: fortran

I tried to compute 97^5 in fortran and have my precision extended to 18 significant figures. When I used integer type for both 97 and 5, the result is -2594335, which is obviously wrong. I know after changing either number to real type will resolve this problem and yield the correct mathematical answer. However, I am curious what specifics in the integer algorithm causes the wrong calculation results when both numbers put in as integers.

```
integer,parameter :: ikind=selected_real_kind(p=18)
real(kind=ikind) :: x,y
print *, 97**5
print *, 97.**5
```

The output of the first line is -2594335, and that of the second line is 8.58734029E+09, which is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of **[integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)**. Your system is using 4-byte integers, which can store values in the range `[-2^31, 2^31-1] = [-2147483648 to 2147483647]` (31 bits for the number and 1 bit for the sign). Because the value of `97^5` is outside of this range, only the least-significant digits will be kept.

When I perform this calculation in Python (which uses unbounded integers), I get

```
>>> (97**5)%(2**32)
4292372961
>>> (97**5)%(2**32) - 2**32
-2594335
```

where I'm subtracting `2^32` on the second line to return to the range of permissible values.

Comment: The righthand side of your expression is evaluated with default integer kind.  You can fix your problem by using a kind type parameter suffix., e.g., `97_ikind**5`.

Comment: Your `sys.maxint = 9223372036854775807` is misleading: Python integers are not bounded. In Python 2.x, the *memory layout* is different for larger integers, but Python will switch automatically. There is no "maxint" in Python.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut You are correct of course. I've edited that detail in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code:

```
integer,parameter :: ikind=selected_real_kind(p=18)
real(kind=ikind) :: x,y
```

`x` and `y` are now defined as `real(kind=ikind)`. On my machine, `ikind` equals 10 and leads to a largest value (`huge(x)`) of about 10 to the power 4932. This is all useless because you do not use the variables afterwards.

```
print *, 97**5
```

This means "default integer 97" to the power "default integer 5". For 32-bit integers, the result (using overflow arithmetics as mentioned by wht) is the one you get.

```
print *, 97.**5
```

This means "default real 97" to the power "default integer 5". For 32-bit reals, the result is correct because it remains within the computable range for 32-bit reals.

TL;DR : In Fortran

- "97" is "default integer kind of value 97"
- "97." is "default real kind of value 97"

To use literal constants of higher precision, use for instance

```
integer,parameter :: rk = selected_real_kind(p=14)
real(kind=rk) :: x

x = 97_rk
```

(This is useless for exact integers as they will be converted properly. For values that cannot be represented exactly in lower precision this is important).